# Why close the discussion "Good JavaScript IDE with jQuery support"?

Tags: discussion, javascript

I'm talking about the discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209126/good-javascript-ide-with-jquery-support, alledgedly closed by you... Here's why I think this should be open:

- It's a question a lot of people ask about javascript/jquery
- Lack of this feature is advanced by some as a reason for not using those technologies
- The question is rated 436 points, whatever that means (sounds impressive, anyway)
- It contains more answers than any page I've found on the web

Comment: None of those are reasons why the question is magically valid for Stack Overflow. Read the notice that explains why it was closed.

Comment: A donkey does not bump into the same stone twice.

Comment: Dude, WebStorm/PHPStorm! What discussion? There is no discussion. `:P`

Comment: This is a site where you turn to with a specific coding issue, that (after putting in some effort) can't seem to fix. Discussing what tools you need/can use is not a subject that fits this description

Comment: Closing it doesn't mean it is gone, it simply prevents new answers. Questions like that also require a lot of maintenance to keep them current.

Comment: What does it have thatn http://google.com/search?q=jquery+ide doesn't have?

Comment: "What does it have that google.com/search?q=jquery+ide doesn't have?" - I followed that link and the *first* item to appear was a link to ... StackOverflow, a post from someone asking basically the same question...

Comment: "A donkey does not bump into the same stone twice" - I wasn't the author of the first question, I was just a dude looking for an answer to that question

Comment: @Francis The *first* link (for me at least) was actually [an article](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-jquery-try-vjet-javascript-ide) advertising a JavaScript IDE named VJET that supports jQuery. This appears to be what you were looking for, no? Similarly, the fourth entry is a Microsoft forums discussion that suggests VS2010 SP1 and also mentions CodeLobster, which is also the seventh link in the search results.

Comment: The eighth link is another IDE with jQuery support, and the last result on the first page is a blog post with a list of IDEs suitable for JS + jQuery development.

Comment: @Asad : thanks for the suggestions. Of course the order of Google answers varies from one occurrence of a request to the next. What I was looking for (and found some of in the now unavailable [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209126/good-javascript-ide-with-jquery-support) ), was the opinion of people who had actually used those tools.

Comment: @Francis If you were seeking opinions on those products, you should look for articles and blog posts (like the ones I mentioned in my comments). Discussion of the merits of software products is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is in this title of your own question: "Why close the **discussion** ...". From the [Stack Overflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask):

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

Also,

> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

These open ended questions are usually better to ask in the [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 6):

As the question currently stands, it is a poll. It asks people for "good" libraries that do X, Y and Z. SO is not a compendium of expert product recommendations, so a question that asks for nothing but a library is outside the scope of the site.

Additionally, questions of the sort you are describing end up with answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409806/1726343):

> have a look at ixedit, You will love it. http://www.ixedit.com/ It is
>   the best for jquery

The answer does not demonstrate why `ixedit` is the best library, or why it fits the criteria in the question, or whether the library is free or commercial. It contains nothing but an assertion that the library solves the OP's problem, and yet it has 49 upvotes from people who presumably use the same library.

Comment: OK, point taken. I understand you want to keep the site from wandering into something messy and uncontrollable. I still don't know where to find answers to the original question (not asked by me, incidentally). A google search to "jquery ide" turned up on top with *another* Stackoverflow post asking a very similar question (not yet rooted out for bad form...)

Answer (score 2):

The close reason says it all:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for guidance

It's an old question from the early days of Stack Overflow when we were still working out what made a good question and what didn't. The information in the question and answers, while useful, isn't a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. It should really be presented in a blog post.

Were this question to be asked today it would be closed very quickly indeed.